# Parameterizing a raw Oracle SQL query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to parameterize a raw SQL query for an Oracle synonym (non-entity) in EF 4 and I am having some problems.  Currently I am doing something like the code below, based on some examples that I saw:

```
 string term="foo";
 OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter("@param1", term);
 object[] parameters = new object[] { p };
 var model = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProjectTask>("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM web_project_task_vw WHERE project_num like '%@param1%') WHERE rownum<=100", parameters).ToList();
```

Running this doesn't return any results.  If I replace the parameter with something like

```
"SELECT * FROM web_project_task_vw WHERE project_num like '%"+term+"%'"
```

it returns the results I expect, but this is obviously a SQL injection risk.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how parameters are supposed to work in EF 4 for an Oracle DB?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought Oracle parameter names started with : instead of @?

Answer (score 9):

First, like Mohammed wrote, you need to prefix the parameter with ':', but not as you define it, just in the query.
Second, you are currently searching not for the value of the parameter but rather strings that contains the string `@param1`. So surround the value of the parameter with % and you should get a result.

So it should look something like this:

```
string term="foo";
 OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter("param1", term);
 object[] parameters = new object[] { p };
 var model = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProjectTask>("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM web_project_task_vw WHERE project_num like '%'||:param1||'%') WHERE rownum<=100", parameters).ToList();
```

Comment: Works in EF6 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your `p` might have an incorrect parameter name; the name should be `param1`, not `@param1`. Your query is also incorrect; replace `'%@param1%'` with `'%:param1%'`.